# default context root for Maven based web applications

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

What is the default context root set when we use Maven based archetype **maven-archetype-webapp** to develop web applications? 
How do we change the default context root in Maven based Projects?

Thanks & Regards

sivakiran B

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to edit the generated `pom.xml` and define a `<webModule>`.

The default context root for a web module is its `ArtifacId`. If you want to change it you will have to add a `<contextRoot>` under `<webModule>`.

Read more on Maven EAR plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-context-root.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @Shmulik